# Using web driver (with c#) how can I verify this span class exists?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, c#-3.0

I'm testing out a third party chrome extension which allows users to speak text inside a Google document.  Here is the code generated inside the Google document:

```
<span class="kix-wordhtmlgenerator-word-node" style="font-size:15px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;">
<span>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTWord 0">I'm</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTSpace 0">&nbsp;</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTWord 1">Speaking</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTSpace 1">&nbsp;</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTWord 2">This</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTSpace 2">&nbsp;</gpldns:gptag>
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTWord 3 googlehighlighted">text</gpldns:gptag>
</span>
```

The specific block of code I'm interested in, is the last span class in the example above:

```
<gpldns:gptag class="googlePLAYRTthWord 3 googlehighlighted">
```

What I need to be able to do is to verify that the class name contains "googlehighlighted".  It doesn't matter what else the class name contains, so long as it contains "googlehighlighted".  Note that in this case the class I'm interested in is the last item but it will not always be the last item

Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks

**EDIT / UPDATE**

For c# I can use the following:

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("googlehighlighted")).Count() > 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test for something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("googlehighlighted")).size() > 0
```

Note that I am using the plural "findElements", which will not cause an Exception in your code if there are zero such elements.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks so much!  I made a few minor edits for c# and got it working perfectly.  I have added it to my question.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for you:

```
IWebElement lastElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='kix-wordhtmlgenerator-word-node']/span/*[last()]"));
if (lastElement.GetAttribute("class").Contains("googlehighlighted")
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Last element class does contain googlehighlighted");
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Last element class does not contain googlehighlighted");
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks so much for your help.  It works fine (so long as the class is the last item but it will not always be).  Unfortunately I can't vote your answer helpful as I don't have enough reputation